# GitLab CI failing after call php in a docker composer exec command

Tags: php, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-exec

[image]

My CI script is failing without any error message, do you guys have any idea why?

```bash
docker compose exec -T my-app-name bash -c 'php -d xdebug.mode=off ./vendor/maglnet/composer-require-checker/bin/composer-require-checker check --output=json > composer-require-check-report.json'

# I also tried variations, always with the same result.

docker compose exec -T my-app-name php -d xdebug.mode=off ./vendor/maglnet/composer-require-checker/bin/composer-require-checker check --output=json > composer-require-check-report.json

docker compose exec -T my-app-name XDEBUG_MODE=off php ./vendor/maglnet/composer-require-checker/bin/composer-require-checker check --output=json > composer-require-check-report.json

docker compose exec -T my-app-name bash -c 'php -d xdebug.mode=off ./vendor/maglnet/composer-require-checker/bin/composer-require-checker check --output=json' > composer-require-check-report.json

docker compose exec -T my-app-name bash -c 'XDEBUG_MODE=off php ./vendor/maglnet/composer-require-checker/bin/composer-require-checker check --output=json > composer-require-check-report.json'
```

As mentioned, the command is executing correctly and the file is generated at the end.

---

The command works well locally (and apparently works well in the runner too), I just don't know why the job is failing.

Comment: What exit code does it have when run locally? Run `echo $?` right after running the command.

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin if you check the discussion [here](https://github.com/maglnet/ComposerRequireChecker/issues/365#issuecomment-1345299289) you'll see how Marco helped me to understand that the job is failing exactly because the command is generating the file. If the output of the command was "empty", then the job would succeed. To fix it, I added `|| true` at the end of the command since I just want the artifact with the report available for now, instead of fail the pipeline.